# QField: Permission denied plan insufficient

Tags: postgis, error, qfield

If i add a PostGIS layer to my QGIS project and try to upload it via QFieldSync i keep getting a error that tells me: "Permission denied because the usersaccount's plan insufficient". But neither the storagespace nor the credentials seem to be the reason for the error.
It only appears when working with PostGIS-layers so i guess the solution has to do with the connection. The database is locally hosted and set to public via pgAdmin.
Has anybody an idea that the reason could be?

[image: Picture of Errormessage on QField]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QFieldCloud Community Plan only allows file based layers, not PostGIS layers.